# Wait for the result of a Firebase Realtime Database Query

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently using the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` method to retrieve a `DataSnapshot` from the local cache as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write. Previously I was using Room and executing callables to query the local sqlite database using `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(callable).get()`, allowing me to store the result in a variable and use it straight away. I can't seem to find a way to do this using Firebase. Is there a way I can use something functionally similar to `await` syntax in other languages to wait until I have a result from the local cache?

Comment: Data is loaded from Firebase (and most modern cloud APIs) asynchronously. Any code that needs the data, needs to be inside the `onDataChange` method or be called from there. See the answers to the questions I linked for some examples of this.

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer that uses the call back is the closest I'll get.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to execute some code after receiving snapshot.But in firebase there is nothing like `await` but you can achieve this by putting code in `addOnCompleteListener` which you want to perform after getting snapshot.